# nullPointerException and how to update label the right way?

Tags: java, class, javafx

I have 2 scenes :
The first one has a "Balance" Label, which displays the balance from a variable.

The second scene is the deposit scene where the user adds to the balance.

(Each scene has its controller class)

I want the balance to be updated when the user goes back to the first scene.
what's the best way to do so? I couldn't find an event for the scene shown, I found online only a stage example which triggers an event when the window is closed, but here I am just changing scenes by changing the mainstage scene.

I have tried making an object of the first scene class inside the second scene's class and calling a method to change the label text when I click the back button but that didn't work.

Here's the code for the first scene where `lbBalance` is the label I want to update, and `updateBal` is the method I am using in the second scene class.

```
public class accountController extends Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Label gilbert;
    @FXML private Label lbBalance;
    @FXML private Button deposit;
    @FXML private Button btn_showBalance;
    private application.depositController depositController;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        lbBalance.setText(String.valueOf(BAL));
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleDeposit(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent depositParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("deposit.fxml"));
        depositScene = new Scene(depositParent);
        mainStage.setScene(depositScene);       
        mainStage.show();
    }

    public void updateBal() {
        lbBalance.setText(String.valueOf(BAL));
    }

}
```

Here's the second scene's class

```
accountController backtoscene= new accountController();
@FXML private Label info;
@FXML private Button btn_depositfinal;
@FXML private TextField depositamount;
@FXML private Button btn_back;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@FXML
public void handleDepositFinal(ActionEvent event) {
    deposit(Integer.parseInt(depositamount.getText()));
    info.setVisible(true);
}

@FXML
public void handleBackButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    backtoscene.updateBal();
    mainStage.setScene(newscene);

}
```

TL;DR calling the method is giving me a nullPointerException, is there any other way to update the balance label when getting back to previous scene?

Comment: check what variable is NULL and instantiate before trying to access it's members

Comment: @Stultuske it's a label so how can it be null? and the value inside the method is surely not null.

Comment: As a side note, is a good idea to start class names in Java with a capital letter. This is discussed in the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Or at least post the full log with the `NullPointerException`

Comment: @JixSas JLabel myLabel; -> this is null, since it isn't instantiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I haven't tested the code, I just wrote it freehand, but it gives you a general idea.

Your main issue is that you are creating a new `AccountController` in the DepositController. Meaning it's a different one than the one you originally instantiated.

```
public class AccountController extends Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Label gilbert;
    @FXML private Label lbBalance;
    @FXML private Button deposit;
    @FXML private Button btn_showBalance;
    private application.DepositController depositController;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        lbBalance.setText(String.valueOf(BAL));
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleDeposit(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("deposit.fxml"));
        Parent depositParent = loader.load();  
        depositScene = new Scene(depositParent);
        depositController = loader.getController();
        depositController .setAccountController(this);

        mainStage.setScene(depositScene);       
        mainStage.show();
    }

    public void updateBal() {
        lbBalance.setText(String.valueOf(BAL));
    }

}
```

Here's the second class where you need to set the AccountController to be the one you originally initialized :

```
public class DepositController extends Controller implements Initializable {
    AccountController backtoscene;
    @FXML private Label info;
    @FXML private Button btn_depositfinal;
    @FXML private TextField depositamount;
    @FXML private Button btn_back;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void setAccountController(AccountController controller){
        backtoscene = controller;
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleDepositFinal(ActionEvent event) {
        deposit(Integer.parseInt(depositamount.getText()));
        info.setVisible(true);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleBackButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        backtoscene.updateBal();
        mainStage.setScene(newscene);

    }
}
```

Now you have access to the AccountController you originally initialized at the start, and the AccountController has access to the correct DepositController.